# My leaflet Map just stopped Loading properly

Tags: javascript, leaflet

My map has been working well, but just recently, only the markers are showing but the rest of the map is not showing. 
Image 1: Map View
[Map view with only markers showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSz1q.png) || Image 2: Console error
[Console error from the map page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DY1OU.png)

Comment: Did you try to load it from incognito tab? Maybe some addon/extension is behaving badly? Also, please create a [mcve] in the question itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaflet uses providers like OpenStreetMap. Sometimes there could be errors related servers.
you can find other provider from here. [Leaflet Map Provider](https://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/)

Comment: nice! you can mark as an answer or vote :)